# My checkbox in a table is immediately unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-events, event-delegation

I have a table with checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked I catch the event with jQuery but this checkbox is immediately unchecked.

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K4uDa

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td><td>AA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td><td>BB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td><td>CC</td>
  </tr>    
</table>


$(function() {

  $("table tr").live("click", function() {
    alert('row clicked');
  });

  $("table tr td input:checkbox").live("click", function() {
   alert('checked/unchecked'); 
   return false;
  });
    
})
```

Where is the problem?

Sorry, I updated my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/K4uDa/1/

I added a 'return false' because I don't want the other event to fire when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Comment: You seem to be clicking the other elements that you've wired the click event for. click on the checkboxes

Comment: Is this one of those tricky questions? If yes, then my answers is - "There is no problem".

Comment: Sorry guys :) I updated my question & jsfiddle. I forgot something

Comment: Usually to avoid things like that I use `.each()`. have you tried that?

Comment: I don't know the '.each()' can you explain how this can help me on this problem?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? as for 1.7, live() is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: use on() instead of live

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way `return false` works is by combining `event.preventDefault()` (which as the name implies prevents the default action of the even, such as un/checking the checkbox, following a link or submitting a form...) and `event.stopPropagation()` (which is what stops the event from propagating to/being 'heard by' its ancestor elements). IE does it a little differently, but effectively you want to retain the default action (the un/checking) while discarding the propagation. So, with that in mind I'd suggest:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K4uDa/14/).

Incidentally, it's worth pointing out that `live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and above (replaced by the `on()` method), and in versions before jQuery 1.7 the docs (for `live()`) recommend using `delegate()` instead.

But given that you're binding events directly to the elements themselves, which suggests they're *not* dynamically added, you may as well simply use the `click()` method directly.

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`window.event.cancelBubble` (at MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms533545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You're using jQuery, it normalizes `stopPropagation`, there is no need to check for `window.event`, or use `cancelBubble`.  Just do `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: +1 great answer, lots of references :). I might add that the way he used `live()` does not imply the elements are not dynamically added. `live()` just worked like this :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa: True, but if you're using `.live` for non-dynamically added elements, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Rocket: I think it's safe to say 'he was doing it wrong' from the question itself. But bažmegakapa's point is accurate, that *is* how `live()` worked, though without more information in the question to address the point it's hard to say whether the `on()`, or the `click()`, method should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `return false`, you should use [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). `return false`, besides stopping propagation (which is what you want), [also prevents the default action](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) triggered by the event, so your checkbox will not be checked.

Also, `live()` is deprecated, so please use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or `delegate()` for <1.7).

```
$("table tr td").on("click", "input:checkbox", function(e) {
    alert('checked/unchecked'); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K4uDa/19/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - you need to stop the event from bubbling, by using `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `return false`

http://jsfiddle.net/K4uDa/16/

Comment: if you examine the order of fired events in my jsfiddle, you'll see that the 'checked/unchecked' alert is displayed. So it is checked but immediately unchecked...

Comment: aye, true. I've confused the click on the row with it. Back to your fiddle!

Comment: updated my answer, see new fiddle! and bažmegakapa's excellent answer who I haven't noticed before answering and explains it much better than my one

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `return false` which stops checking the checkbox.

Comment: Yes but how can I fire the check event and prevent the row click event? Because the row click should allow me to navigate to another page...